# Mongoid 5.0 support for $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Does anyone know if latest 5.0 version of Mongoid gem supports [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) ?

Nothing mentioned [mongoid docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/).

Comment: I \*think* this is the JIRA issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4251

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the mongo shell query for lookup into mongoid query like this. I was a pain to figure this out. So posting here if it helps anyone.

```
clookup =     {
'$lookup': {
    'from': "contacts",
    'localField': "_id",
    'foreignField': "account_id",
    'as': "contacts"
    }
}

sort = { '$sort': { '_id.year': 1, '_id.month': 1 } }

docs = Account.collection.aggregate([clookup, sort])
pp docs.first
```